# MongoDB - Clearing the cache using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, caching, pymongo

I'm using PyMongo to access MongoDB and I want to make some speed tests. However, the fact MongoDB uses cache makes it harder for me to do that. I know it's possible to [clear cache using the Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/PlanCache.clear/#PlanCache.clear) (I hope that's what I need) - but I can't find how to do that using PyMongo. Is it even possible? Thank you

Comment: why would you need to clear mongo cache ? what kind of speed test you are doing that require to clear cache ?

Comment: I want to perform the same query several times so I can determine it's average speed. When Mongo caches the queries, the queries after the first one are much faster than the first one

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong, base on this doc mongodb does not handle query cache (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-handle-caching). If you want to optimize your query performance you need to do it through index (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/#index-introduction)

Comment: I'm not currently looking for optimizing the performance (and I am indeed using indexes). I'm looking to test the current set-up of the DB. According to the link you sent - they do cache the latest query indexes in RAM. I'm looking for a way to clear that, like in the link I attached in my question.

Comment: you can use `cursor.explain()` as it ignore the query plan cache (ref: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/#query-plan-revision). pymongo do have that (http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html?highlight=hint#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.explain) so you can try to see if  it work ?

Comment: I don't see how will it help. I want to test the times, not just read the plan

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to execute the `PlanCache.clear()` command in PyMongo:

```
db.command(
    {
        "planCacheClear": "collection_name"
    }
)
```